# Swift 2.0 NSPlaceholderDictionary attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, ios9

I ran into a problem which I seem to can't fix. 
Whenever I try to run my app (XCode 7 BETA 2) on my device (iOS 9 BETA 2) it crashes at AppDelegate with the following error:

```
2015-06-24 04:12:46.769 eSports Center 2[1472:96321] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18433738c 0x1989dbf2c 0x184224da8 0x184224c40 0x100204efc 0x10020508c 0x1001fc968 0x1002027c8 0x18422d360 0x18422d1d0 0x100201f74 0x1001fc3f8 0x1898be414 0x1890f23c0 0x1890ed008 0x1898d48c4 0x1002281bc 0x1898be414 0x1890f23c0 0x1890ed008 0x1898d48c4 0x189981188 0x18997ec00 0x189997048 0x189996d58 0x189996a60 0x1898fc19c 0x1898fa518 0x18998a974 0x1899808c0 0x18997fa90 0x18997f6b8 0x18997f620 0x1898be414 0x1890f23c0 0x1890ed008 0x1890ecec8 0x1890ec594 0x1890ec2e8 0x1890e5ab8 0x1842ee39c 0x1842ec114 0x1842190f0 0x18992f838 0x18992a5f0 0x1001192ac 0x19921a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

When I try to run it on the Simulator everything is fine. The App itself is a recode of my current project in Swift 2.0 with some pods (for the first time).

It includes 3 libs and some basic UI stuff, I tried to setup the first TabController tab.

Someone has an idea of how to fix them?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in application did finish loading and then step through the project until you can see what nil reference is causing the crash. Present that code (where the error happens) and someone will restate that the object must be initialized. You can try an if let or do try to handle the nil or catch the error.

Comment: To see the actual statement that is causing the error add an exception breakpoint:

From the Mian Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint. Then right-click the breakpoint and add an action: "po $arg1". Run the app to get the breakpoint and you will be at the line that causes the exception and the error message will be in the debugger console.

/Users/dan/Dropbox/SO-Images/ExecptionBreakpoint1.png

Add action:
po $arg1
/Users/dan/Dropbox/SO-Images/ExceptionPO.png

Answer (score 0):

Everything Is working now. One library I'm using, tried to load a Font which wasn't available on my iPhone but on my Simulator (?).
Thanks for all the help, Breakpoint and stepping through the Library code did the trick!